# Problema al ejecutar APK react-native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Estoy aprendiendo react-native e hice una app la cual quiero exportar para que un amigo la use, genere el apk pero al momento de mi amigo instalar el apk le sale el siguiente error.

```
able to load script make sure you are either running a metro server or that your bundle "index.android.bundle" is packaged correctly for release
```

No se el porque se debe, o si estuve haciendolo mal, lo estaba haciendo por la [Documentación oficial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#migrating-old-android-react-native-apps-to-use-app-signing-by-google-play)

Estoy haciendolo por el metodo correcto o que me esta haciendo falta?

Comment: Intenta con el siguiente comando `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` [Fuente](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25348)

Comment: Hola Rafael, recuerda agregar en tus preguntas lo que tratas,saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estas construyendo el APK de esta forma:

```
react-native run-android
```

Si obtienes el error:

> Unable to load script make sure you are either running a metro server
> or that your bundle

Antes de debes iniciar el empaquetado con

```
npm start
```

o

```
react-native start
```